# Use ObjectBox with Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, objectbox

**UPDATE: SOLVED! READ MY OWN ANSWER WHICH I ACCEPTED!**

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm trying to use ObjectBox in my Libgdx Android project.

However, when I follow the Android guide my app crashes

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
```

I see there is a desktop gradle setup, should I be using this do you think? As a Libgdx isn't really an Android project, it's pure java in an LWJGL that just sits in an empty Activity.

Anyone got this working?

(I know it's niche and a long shot...)

EDIT:

I've done some more digging and looked in the apk under the lib folder, on the apk using ObjectBox, I have 4 folders

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
x86
```

On the apk without ObjectBox (which works) I have

```
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
x86
```

In the arm64-v8a folder there is nothing for libgdx. Seeing as my device is that type, I assume it's looking for it and finding nothing. Hold on, that gives me an idea...

Comment: Is that happening on an x86 emulator or an ARM device?

Comment: Ummmmm on my Galaxy S8!? Checking and it says arm64-v8a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So because ObjectBox creates .so files for the additional modern folder of arm64-v8a, and my libgdx setup didn't have the lines

```
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"

file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
```

as my phone uses that folder (when it can) it wasn't finding any gdx files to use.

After adding the above lines to my gradle files everything worked fine.

My phone (Samsung S8) uses arm64-v8a, so it uses that folder if it exists. I can only assume if the folder is missing it defaults to a diff folder, but once it finds it, it searches there and nowhere else.

Thanks to Xiao for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I reckon you move the solution to this answer and accept it, in case anyone else has the same issues